# Cant echo preg_match_all as it needed

Tags: php, echo

I  have an XML file with the following content:

```
<property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="2"   name="ALALALAL"><vt:lpwstr>asdasda</vt:lpwstr></property><property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="3" name="MACABSZ"><vt:lpwstr>ooooo</vt:lpwstr></property><property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="4" name="3"><vt:lpwstr>c</vt:lpwstr></property><property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="5" name="4"><vt:lpwstr>d</vt:lpwstr></property>
```

I have the following php. (I am able to fine desired parts of the xml):

```
   if (preg_match_all ('_name="(.*?)"_',  $ekker, $tomb2)); 
   if (preg_match_all ('_<vt:lpwstr>(.*?)</vt:lpwstr>_',  $ekker, $tomb));
```

In an html file I want to echo the results, so I use this:

```
<form>
  <?php 
  foreach ($tomb2[1] as $metaname); 
  foreach ($tomb[1] as $talalat){
  echo '<p>' . "$metaname\n" . '</p>' . '<br>' . '<input type="text" name="firstname" value="' . "$talalat\n" . '">' . '<br>';}?>
</form>
```

As a result I get this:

[image]

However this is not exactly what I want. Instead of the first three "4" I need: ALALALAL, MACABSZ, 3. Why does it echo only the last result of the '*name="(.*?)"*' search?

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I get, what you want is to access both arrays items with same index in one single loop. Maybe this will do :

```
<form>
<?php 
    foreach ($tomb2[1] as $key => $metaname){
        $talalat = $tomb[1][$key];
        echo '<p>' . "$metaname\n" . '</p>' . '<br>' . '<input type="text" name="firstname" value="' . "$talalat\n" . '">' . '<br>';
    }
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I get 16  fields. In the XML there is only 4 + 4 name. So I need only 
ALALALAL - asdasda
MACABSZ - ooooo

Comment: sorry, I didn't get what you wanted. I'll update the answer.